# show hidden directory in java

Tags: java, windows

I use the

```
String[] cmd = {"attrib", "+h", files/folder path};
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

to hide a directory and it successfully hidden.  Then how do I get it back to visible.??

Answer (score 0):

[to reset `h` flag use `-h`    for windows](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/attrib.mspx?mfr=true)

```
attrib -h
```

Comment: It simple as that...I new to java and am little surprised by that anyway thank so much you saved my day..

Comment: this wasn't related to java, however you are forcing java to be platform dependent here, not too good thing to do, if this answers your question you should mark it as answered

Comment: sorry...i related it to java since i'm using eclipse to write java program, i'm new to java and not knowing that answered question should be marked..but now i know so apologies and thanks...